# Magento 2.4.4 oAuth

Tags: magento2.4.4, oauth

I'm trying to set up an integration on Magento 2.4.4 but this is not working.
The other side are reporting this error coming from Magento:

"Signature method HMAC-SHA1 is not supported"

Other integrations are working fine but I can't find any kind of logging on my end.

How can I debug this this to find out what the issue is?

From what I understand HMAC-SHA1 is supported by Magento
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

Comment: Have you tried simulating the requests in something like Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Community Edition 2.4.4.

According to the \Magento\Framework\Oauth\OauthInterface constants, SHA1 has been deprecated. By using `HMAC-SHA256` I could get past the signature error.

```
     * Signature Methods
     */
    /**
     * @deprecated SHA1 is deprecated
     * @see SIGNATURE_SHA256
     */
    const SIGNATURE_SHA1 = 'HMAC-SHA1';

    const SIGNATURE_SHA256 = 'HMAC-SHA256';
```

Comment: For now I just re-enabled HMAC-SHA1.
Obviously SHA1 has to go sometime but too many people still use it and I understood that it was still just about sufficient for HMAC?

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation wasn't updated in line with the source code. The best I can offer is a Magento issue on GitHub, hopefully the ticket discussion can shed some light - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35510